# "The cheater's coin" python riddle

Tags: python

I tried for hours to solve this python riddle in my level of knowledge and I don't know what to write past the thinking part "I need to make tails more frequent by using +1 to something" maybe. The riddle goes like that:

```
import random
def broken_coin():
    if random.random() <= 0.9:
        return "Heads"
    return "Tails"
```

> using no random source part of the function(which you can't edit), and turn the coin into a standard one: if you print the code the chances for heads will be 50% and the chances for tails will be 50%

thanks early to anyone who commented :)

EDIT: added what was my idea

Comment: What did you get out of the "thinking part"?

Comment: Hint: You'll have to throw the coin multiple times in a wrapper func.

Comment: @LMD the thing is I can't use that

Comment: @LMD Or just [repair it](https://tio.run/##bU5BCoMwELznFUt7SaBIpJdW6r0P6E1Eosa6VJOwiYe@3ka0UKFzWXZmZ3bcO/TWnC@O5hlHZykAKdPakbFWd1CTfWlTNRYNFxmDCOy2i2QdXMAtB5lcV3kB6TCRgcNdq9Yf2C/1UDhEih0j4xQSYGC7OMhhUGPdquz7puktNpoX8gRpKRZr0D5EY8ZI@2kIPnqKXVPoLEEFaJaMp@aplFKUzBGawDdT0tgpbltJIf6ra18h5vkD) :-)

Comment: @ElectricIceWolf LMD means write a function `coin` that uses (calls) `broken_coin` (multiple times). You can certainly do that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If I read your problem correctly, you need to provide a method to compensate for the broken coin producing a relatively fair amount of results.  With that instead of calling the broken_coin() function every time directly, one could call a function that calls the function and every other time returns the reverse result to the calling function.

After reading the comments about what could or could not be used, I've updated my sample code.

```
import random

def broken_coin():
    if random.random() <= 0.9:
        return "Heads"
    return "Tails"
    
def fix_coin(j):

    if j == 0:
        return broken_coin()

    coin = broken_coin()
    
    if (coin == "Heads"):
        return "Tails"
    else:
        return "Heads"

for x in range (100):
    print(fix_coin(x %2))
```

See if this more closely fulfils the spirit of the problem.

Regards.

Comment: That's bad. Should have 50/50 chance every single time. Not alternating between 90/10 and 10/90.

Comment: thank you very much but I'm not sure that I can use global is there a way without using global?

Comment: Yes.  Actually there would be a simpler way.  Instead of "if EVEN == 0:" you could just use "if random.random() > 0.5:".  Regards,

Comment: Of course you're not allowed to do `random.random() > 0.5`, otherwise you wouldn't even need to use the broken coin at all and the riddle would be pointless.

Comment: I didn't see reusing random a second time as a restriction, but if so, I edited the code so that the random function is not reused.  It may not get style points but it provides the expectation of 50% heads and 50% tails.

Comment: Still has the problem I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: thank you @NoDakker +everyone that commented I think this is the answer I was looking for! :)

Comment: @ElectricIceWolf Oh so *you* created that riddle? Because if not, then this is most certainly **not** an acceptable answer.

Comment: @KellyBundy no I didn't make the riddle but the only problems are the level of coding that is allowed. so when the creator will be available I'll check this and edit that comment